# How do I select elements that are not preceded by another certain element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a HTML structure as follows, with repeating pairs of img and p tags. In many cases, the img is not present.

```
<img>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
```

I wish to select all p tags that are not immediately preceded by an img.

I can select p tags that *are* preceded by img:

```
img + p {}
```

How do I select the inverse? - ie, p tags that are not preceded by img?

Comment: If your html always has a `p` tag preceding the next `p` tag when the `img` tag is excluded, then you could just do `p + p {}`

Comment: In addition to @benvc's suggestion, `p:first-child, p + p` if a p may also appear first.

Comment: How about `:not(img) + p {}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being that there isn't a "previous sibling" selector, you could style your standard `p` elements, and then overwrite the ones that *are* preceded by an `img` with the default styling.

You're probably better off wrapping this in a container though, just so you're not styling every `p` on the page.

```css
.container > p {
  color: red;
}

.container > img + p {
  color: black;
}

/* DEMO PURPOSES */
img { display: none; } img, p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img />
    <p>This is preceded by img</p>
    <img />
    <p>This is preceded by img</p>
    <img />
    <p>This is preceded by img</p>
    <p>This is not preceded by img</p>
    <p>This is not preceded by img</p>
    <img />
    <p>This is preceded by img</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Till the point that I am writing this answer, `CSS` doesn't provide a selector for the previous element.

For your case, and as a workaround, let's say that these `p` and `img` tags are placed in a wrapping `div.wrapper`, consider trying this:

```css
.wrapper > img + p ~ p {
   color: red;
}
.wrapper > img + p {
   color: black !important;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
 <img style="height:20px;display:block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" />
 <p>unaffected</p>
 <p>affected</p>
 <p>affected</p>
 <img style="height:20px;display:block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" />
 <p>unaffected</p>
 <p>affected</p>
 <img style="height:20px;display:block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" />
 <p>unaffected</p>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.